# .htaccess not removing this: index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

So, I've recently coded a PHP API for one of my websites, but I am trying to make it remove the ?

Along with `index.php` so let's say I go to http://api.url.com/index.php?Method

I could actually go to http://api.url.com/Method and it work the same as it would.

I've tried other **.htaccess's** but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write Below Code in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That isn't working. I've already restarted apache2. It just comes up with 404 when I go to http://api.url.com/Method=Test

(I've replaced url.com with my url)

Comment: show my edit answer

Comment: That isn't working either. I've confirmed mod_rewrite is enabled and installed on my ubuntu 14.04 apache2 installation. It still returns a 404

Comment: That edit allows me to put a forward slash after the index.php like this. http://api.url.com/index.php/Method=Test

Comment: one more time you confirm rewrite mod is enable follow this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04